# Display date in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have 3 buttons i.e for week,previous and next. On click of week button it will display the date selected in textbox and 6 days added to it `(for example 26 Jun 2013-2 Jul 2013 )`.
 On click of previous button it will display as `19 Jun 2013-26 Jun 2013` in textbox.
On click of next button it will display `2 Jul 2013-8 Jul 2013` in textbox.
 And the process continues.I want how this will be done in `javascript`.

```
enter code here


 <input type="text" id="txtdatetimeshow" readonly="readonly"  
   style="height: 25px; width: 150px;
   font-size: medium; font-family: Times New Roman;"   runat="server"    />

    <input type="button" id="showweekbtn" runat="server" value="week"/>
    <input type="button" id="sfprevbtn" runat="server" value="prev"/>
    <input type="button" id="sfnextbtn" runat="server" value="next"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {

    var today=new Date();
    var date=today.getDate();
    var month=today.getMonth();
    var year= today.getFullYear();
    var month_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",   
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    var NextDate= new Date(year, month, date);//today's date
    var weekdate=new Date(NextDate);
    weekdate.setDate(weekdate.getDate()+6);//add 6 days to the date
    var Ndate=NextDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month]+"  "+NextDate.getFullYear()+"-"+" "+weekdate.getDate()+"   "+month_names[weekdate.getMonth()]+" "+weekdate.getFullYear();

    var nextWeekDate=new Date(weekdate);
    nextWeekDate.setDate(weekdate.getDate()+6);
    var NWdate=weekdate.getDate()+" "+month_names[weekdate.getMonth()]+" "+weekdate.getFullYear()+"-"+""+nextWeekDate.getDate()+"  "+month_names[nextWeekDate.getMonth()]+" "+nextWeekDate.getFullYear();

    var prevWeekDate=new Date(NextDate);
    prevWeekDate.setDate(NextDate.getDate()-6);//subtract 6 days to date
    var PWdate=prevWeekDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[prevWeekDate.getMonth()]+" "+prevWeekDate.getFullYear()+"-"+NextDate.getDate()+"  "+month_names[NextDate.getMonth()]+" "+NextDate.getFullYear();

    //to show previous date
    $("#sfprevbtn").click(function() 
        {
       var prevDate=new Date(year,month,date-1);
       var pdate=prevDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month] +" "+prevDate.getFullYear();
       $("#txtdatetimeshow").val(PWdate);

    });
    //to show next date
    $("#sfnextbtn").click(function()
         {

        var nextDate=new Date(year,month,date+1);
        var Ndate=nextDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[month] +" "+nextDate.getFullYear();
        $("#txtdatetimeshow").val(NWdate);
    });

        //to show week view
        $("#showweekbtn").click(function() 
        {
          $("#txtdatetimeshow").val(Ndate);

         });


          });

</script>
```

Comment: What code do you have allready? What have you tried?

Comment: I had posted my code. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var date = new Date('2013','06','26');
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
```

Comment: but i dont want to hardcode my date.I has to take todays day by default.Please tell me how to get that?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is some JavaScript that will continue to increment/decrement the week range as you click on the next/prev buttons, beyond just a single week before/after the current one.

The problem with your original code is that you had in effect hard-coded the next/previous week strings, as your next/prev buttons didn't actually change their values. I wrote some code based on yours that does (what I hope) you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var current=new Date();
    var month_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",   
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    getWeek(0);

    //to show previous date
    $("#sfprevbtn").click(function() 
    {
       getWeek(-1);
    });

    //to show next date
    $("#sfnextbtn").click(function()
    {
        getWeek(1);
    });

    //to show week view
    $("#showweekbtn").click(function() 
    {
        current=new Date();
        getWeek(0);
    });

    function getWeek(weeks){
        current = new Date(current.getTime() + weeks * 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        var newDate = new Date(current.getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var dateString=current.getDate()+" "+month_names[current.getMonth()] +" "+current.getFullYear() + " - " + newDate.getDate()+" "+month_names[newDate.getMonth()] +" "+newDate.getFullYear();
        $("#txtdatetimeshow").val(dateString);
    }
});
```

You'll note I wrote a function, getWeek(), which calculates the next week interval based on the initial date. The "current" date starts at today's date, but increases/decreases accordingly as you click on next/prev to see different week intervals. The "week" button isn't really necessary at this point, but I left it there so if you click on it, it will return you to the week of the current date.

I hope this helps you out. If this isn't what you're looking for, please let me know and I'll be happy the help you further. Happy scripting!

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment to another answer:

### JavaScript

```
var date = new Date();

/* IMPORTANT PART */
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
/* ------ */
var d = (date.getDate().toString()+" "+(parseInt(date.getMonth(),10) +1)+ " "+date.getFullYear().toString()).split(" ");

if(d[0].length == 1)
    d[0] = "0"+d[0];

if(d[1].length == 1)
    d[1] = "0"+d[1];

alert(d.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> function displayDate()
>   {

var today=new Date();

```
        var date=today.toISOString().slice(0, -14);
        // Strip last 14 characters, ISO format is like
        // 2012-12-30T17:41:49.027Z but we want
        // 2012-12-30

        document.getElementById("fname").value=date;
     }
```